# How to make Jtable cell character length

Tags: java, jtable

I want to make my j table column to limit character like allowed only 16 character.I tried various methods nothing works.can anybody helps me?.

Comment: Discuss in brief what have you tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer found here https://community.oracle.com/thread/1482301

"Custom Cell Editors
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext
and a custom document on a JTextField

One example worth thousand words"

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test2 extends JFrame {
  public Test2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container content = getContentPane();
    String[] head = {"One","Two","Three"};
    String[][] data = {{"R1-C1", "12345678", "R1-C3"},
                       {"R2-C1", "R2-C2", "R2-C3"},
                       {"R3-C1", "R3-C2", "R3-C3"}};
    JTable jt = new JTable(data, head);
    content.add(new JScrollPane(jt), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
    jtf.setDocument(new LimitedPlainDocument(10));
    jt.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jtf));
    setSize(300,300);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) { new Test2().setVisible(true); }
}
class LimitedPlainDocument extends javax.swing.text.PlainDocument {
  private int maxLen = -1;
  /** Creates a new instance of LimitedPlainDocument */     
  public LimitedPlainDocument() {}
  public LimitedPlainDocument(int maxLen) { this.maxLen = maxLen; }
  public void insertString(int param, String str, 
                           javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attributeSet) 
                      throws javax.swing.text.BadLocationException {
    if (str != null && maxLen > 0 && this.getLength() + str.length() > maxLen) {
      java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
      return;
    }
    super.insertString(param, str, attributeSet);
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3820014, works fine for me. You do realize the "2nd column" is the column that is restricted to 10 characters. @Biminimus, the newer approach to limiting characters in a text field is to use a `DocumentFilter`. Check out the section in the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for code using this approach. (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did

The Call:

```
    JTable table = new JTable();
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    limitCharacters(jtf, 16);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jtf));
```

The limitCharacters Method:

```
private void limitCharacters(JTextField textField, final int limit) {
     PlainDocument document = (PlainDocument) textField.getDocument();

     document.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                throws BadLocationException {
            String string = fb.getDocument().getText(0,
                    fb.getDocument().getLength())
                    + text;

            if (string.length() <= limit)
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs); 
        }

    });
}
```