# JTable Limit / Filter characters from user Input

Tags: java

I'm developing an application which has `JTables` to get data from users.

Now, my need is, When user **type** something in a `JTable` cell He/She can type below letters & symbols only.

> A B C D E F G # - [ ]

And also I want to limit the characters to 10 in a cell.

Comment: You may have to implement customized TableCellEditor. Please refer following reference http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=333472&seqNum=3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779236/how-to-make-jtable-cell-character-length

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still can't solve this.